# How can I solve the error below while trying to knit codes into PDF

Tags: rmarkdown

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.80 cat(``Times Table for,n,:\n
                                '') for (i in 1:table\_size) \{
```

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Loop-controls.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Loop-controls.log for more info.
Execution halted

Comment: you have used an undefined command `\n`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback@DavidCarlisle. Much appreciated. How can I address it to be able to print my codes and output in PDF?

Comment: You have given no indication of your input or desired output so I can not guess what you shold change all we know is you have used a command `\n` that is not defined.  You could simply remove it from thr input and the error would go but I don't know if it is the output you want

Comment: If you are looking to replace `\n` (in the input) with a newline (in the output), you can try `\\ ` (space only there to aid formatting, which is a line-break), or a blank line (which will start a new paragraph). But, like @DavidCarlisle, I don't know if it is the output you want.